# WPF on Windows 7 with touch: hide touch cursor

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, touch

I have a WPF application that, due to hardware constraints, has to run on Windows 7 Standard Embedded. The device is touch enabled and I am taking advantage of that in the way that I am building the application.

One of the problems that I have is that whenever the user touches the screen, a small "pointer" appears showing where the user has touched. This can apparently be turned on and off at a system level (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-the-touch-pointer-on-or-off) however ideally I want to turn it off at a WPF application/form level so that the user is not having to disable and enable the cursor each time they go in and out of the application.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how this can be achieved? I have tried searching various combinations of Windows 7, Touch, Pointer etc. but bar the above article I only ever seem to come back with how to enable touch events.

I should also point out that the hardware constraints currently rule out any option of upgrading to Windows 8, 8.1 or 10 so please do not consider this in any answer you may have.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following properties of the Window to false...

- Stylus.IsTapFeedbackEnabled
- Stylus.IsTouchFeedbackEnabled
- Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled
- Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled

They are probably not all required; but this worked for me.